# Apple iOS Application with password and login

Tags: ios, web-applications, appstore-approval

I want to ask if I created an application and user can install it.

But when opening the app he will see only a background image with a login button that ask him to put a password and than he can use the application.

It will work like that? the Apple tester will approve it?

Comment: It might depend on what happens *after* logging in. But there's nothing wrong with the fundamental flow, many big apps do it this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is nothing wrong in this process/flow.